# asymptotic families of ramanujan near-integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

This is a follow-up to the question on the Ramanujan constant.

Can one find an asymptotic family of shockingly near-integers obtained by raising e to some simple algebraic number, in the spirit of Ramanujan's 
$|\exp(\pi \sqrt{163}) - \text{ some integer }| \le 10^{-12}$? Single numerical coincidences don't impress me (and for good reason too ...).

Is there a sequence of such near-integers, whose nearness to integers is closer than what you know exists by pigeonholing exp(alpha) for all alpha of bounded "height" or "complexity"?

Answer (score 6):

The Ramanujan behavior is typically explained by the fact that the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-163})$ has class number one (together with an integrality property of the j-function - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Almost_integers_and_Ramanujan.27s_constant)).  Since there are only finitely many such imaginary quadratic fields, you can't really expect to have infinitely many similar phenomena (at least admitting a similar explanation).